# Command to see how many application PowerShell returns?

Tags: powershell

I can count the "Aliases".

(Get-...).Count

I am looking for the total strength of applications.

What should write in the dotted area above?

Comment: What is _the total strength of applications_ ???

Comment: Are you looking for `(Get-Command -Type Application).Count`?

Comment: The number of applications in a directory @Theo